# Gradle Xcode Plugin - xcodebuild task fails

Tags: ios, xcode, gradle

I've started experimenting with the [Openbakery Gradle Xcode Plugin](http://openbakery.org/gradle.html) and I've added this `build.gradle` file to my iOS Cocoa Touch Framework project:

```
plugins {
    id "org.openbakery.xcode-plugin" version "0.11.4"
}

xcodebuild {
    target = 'RetailSDK'
}
```

If I run the `build` Gradle task or the `xcodebuild` Gradle task, the `xcodebuild` step fails with output as follows:

```
:iOS:cocoapods
:iOS:xcodebuildConfig
:iOS:infoplistModify
Updating /Users/AdilHussain/Work/client-sdk/iOS/RetailSDK/Info.plist
Nothing was modifed!
:iOS:keychainClean
:iOS:keychainCreate SKIPPED
:iOS:provisioningClean
:iOS:provisioningInstall SKIPPED
:iOS:xcodebuild
xcodebuild: error: The flag -scheme is required when specifying -derivedDataPath.

Done
:iOS:keychainRemove

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

The `build` folder in my iOS Framework project following the build contains no `RetailSDK.framework` output; only a `project.plist` file and an `xcodebuild-output.txt` file with the same error message as what is printed in the terminal, i.e.

```
xcodebuild: error: The flag -scheme is required when specifying -derivedDataPath.
```

Interestingly enough, this error message is also visible at the bottom of [this](http://openbakery.org/getting-started.html) Getting Started document.

So, question is: is it possible to build an iOS Cocoa Touch Framework project using this plugin and, if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it should be possible to build a framework using the gradle plugin.

In your project the scheme setting is missing.

e.g.

```
xcodebuild {
   target = 'mytarget'
   scheme = 'myscheme'
}
```

You find several examples in the examples folder here: https://github.com/openbakery/gradle-xcodePlugin

Comment: Thanks for the response Rene. I tried adding the *scheme* setting but now the build is failing with a whole host of "fatal error: could not build module 'Foundation'" and "could not build module 'Darwin'" error messages. I've had a look at the *xcodebuild* command that is run and interestingly if I change the "-sdk iphonesimulator" parameter to "-sdk iphoneos" and run it in Terminal, the build succeeds. Any ideas?

Comment: Ignore previous comment. Turns out the Getting Started document that I followed had the old version of the plugin. I've now bumped it up from "0.11.4" to "0.12.5" and some of the *build.gradle* parameters which were previously not working are starting to work. Exciting! Thanks for the support.  Worth mentioning for anyone else stumbling across this thread that I had to had the *xcodebuild.destination.platform* and *xcodebuild.destination.os* parameters before the *xcodebuild* command started to work.